# JSP getParameter problem

Tags: jsp, servlets, parameters, request

I have a form, if the timer reach the form will auto redirect to the Servlet to update database. My problem now is if javascript redirect the window to servlet my request.getParameter is null.

```
function verify(f,whichCase){
if(whichCase == "Submit"){
    msg = "Are you sure that you want to submit this test?";
    var i = confirm(msg)
    if(i){
        parent.window.location = "sindex.jsp"
    }
   return i;
 }
}
```

I doing this because i got a iframe in my jsp. Timer update problem have to use iframe. So, when time up or user click submit  parent.window.location can let me refresh parent window

```
<form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/TestServlet" onSubmit="return verify(this,whichPressed)">
```

My form when user click submit button within the timing, it will trigger the verify function to let user confirm submit. So inside my TestServlet i got this, because using javascript redirect request.getParameter("answer") this keep return me null.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
if (request.getParameter("Submit") != null) {
   String ans = request.getParameter("answer");
   Answer a = new Answer(ans, no);
   aa.CreateAnswer(an,t.getTestCode(),username);
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/sindex.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

Below are my timer when time up redirect to TestServlet trigger the doGet method

```
if((mins == 0) && (secs == 0)) {
window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to submit the test."); // change timeout message as required
var sUrl = "TestServlet";
parent.window.location = sUrl // redirects to specified page once timer ends and ok button is pressed
} else {
  cd = setTimeout("redo()",1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have understood the issue, but i think your problem is here:

```
if((mins == 0) && (secs == 0)) {
window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to submit the test."); // change timeout message as required
var sUrl = "TestServlet";
parent.window.location = sUrl // redirects to specified page once timer ends and ok button is pressed
} else {
  cd = setTimeout("redo()",1000);
}
```

You are redirecting to TestServlet but you are not sending any parameter because you are not submitting your form. Try something like this:

```
    if((mins == 0) && (secs == 0)) {
    window.alert("Time is up. Press OK to submit the test."); // change timeout message as required
    var sUrl = "TestServlet";
    //myform it's a variable pointing to your form
    myform.submit();
    } else {
      cd = setTimeout("redo()",1000);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi because that form is inside a iframe